# Url In Get request updates, but return from get request doesn't Update

Tags: json, excel, vba, get, request

I have a get request which calls gets the json data with an API Key. When I test the url in a browser, it works fine with all the updated data from the api key. When I return the data from the API key in my VBA Function, it still shows the previous data.

The url updates, however for some reason the variable holding the json data called from the url does not update and so still contains the old data.

When I shut down the excel sheet, and reopen it, the variable then updates to the latest data. I have been stuck for a day and a half now, any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the relevant code:

```
Public Function getHTTP(ByVal url As String) As String
  Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
  With xmlhttp
    .Open "GET", url, False: .send
    getHTTP = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
  End With
End Function

Function callingGetReq()
     Dim stage1 As String
     stage1 = "x"
    callingGetReq = " "
    Worksheets("Hub Api Data Sheet").Range("B4", "B2").Clear
    
    Dim email As String
    email = Worksheets("Dom. Inputs").Range("B28").Value
    Dim url As String
    Dim api_key As String
    api_key = "?hapikey=#####################################"
    Dim count As String
    count = "&count=1"
    Dim property As String
    property = "&property=customer_number&property=salutation&property=firstname&property=lastname&property=email&property=zip&property=address&property=city&property=state&property=address_line_2&property=hs_searchable_calculated_phone_number"
    Dim propertyMode As String
    propertyMode = "&propertyMode=value_only"
    Dim formSub As String
    formSub = "&formSubmissionMode=newest"
    Dim listMem As String
    listMem = "&showListMemberships=true"
    url = "https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact/email/" + email + "/profile" + api_key + propertyMode + property + formSub + listMem
   
    MsgBox
    
    stage1 = getHTTP(url)
    callingGetReq = stage1
    Worksheets("Hub Api Data Sheet").Range("B4") = callingGetReq

    Worksheets("Hub Api Data Sheet").Range("B2") = url
    ' ActiveCell = " " + callingGetReq + " "
End Function
```

Among other solutions, I have tried to clear the variable but this doesn't help...

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: vba use "&" For String concat not "+". buy the way why Msgbox is alone ?

Comment: That was a test to check the value. I forgot to comment it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How is the `callingGetReq()` function being called? It seems like the only parameter that can change when calling the API is the `email` variable. Everything else is hardcoded. It also seems that you're always calling the API using the same value for `email`. Unless this `Worksheets("Dom. Inputs").Range("B28").Value` is being updated somehow. Calling the API with the same parameters all the time will return the same result. Unless the data that corresponds to the specific `email` is being dynamically updated. Is that the case?

Comment: @StavrosJon. The email is the specific id to the data for each individual customer in the database. When I call the url in the browser, the data is up to date. When I call the IDENTICAL URL in the excel get request, the data returned is old. I am thinking this is something to do with the Excel Cache?